# How to list all references to memory from selected memory region in ghidra?

Tags: decompilation, ghidra

I want to find all peripherals used by firmware dumped from embedded device. I loaded SVD file to add registers into memory map. Now I can find a peripheral in the memory region and check if there are any references to that peripheral.

Is there any way to find all references for given memory region at once to find all peripherals that are used? Preferably to multiple memory regions, since svd-loader script for ghidra groups peripherals into multiple memory regions.